# Как исправить hostname для postgres в docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, jar, dockerfile

При запуске приложения ловлю ошибку:

> Ошибка:springboot-postgresql | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
> Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port
> are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Я так понимаю приложение долбится на localhost : 5432.
А для моего приложения в контейнере контейнер с БД точно не на локалхосте должен быть.
Как пофискить?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
RUN mkdir -p /home/tst
WORKDIR /home/test
COPY . /home/test
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/test/hybridclient.jar"]
test@test:~$
```

Dockerfile.postgres:

```
FROM postgres:12
EXPOSE 5432
```

docker-compoose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: springboot-postgresql
    image: springboot-app
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
  postgresqldb:
    image: postgres
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=111111
      - POSTGRES_USER=usrdb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас приложение использует spring boot. В этом случае нужно приложению сконфигурировать [параметры соединения с БД](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data).

Добавьте в конфигурацию сервиса `app` секцию `environment`:

```
  app:
    container_name: springboot-postgresql
    image: springboot-app
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/usrdb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=usrdb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=111111
```

Тут важно отметить несколько моментов:

1. БД запускается в отдельном контейнере, и она недоступна из контейнера приложения по `localhost`.
2. в контейнере сервиса `app` контейнер с постгрес [доступен по имени хоста](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), которое совпадает с именем сервиса в docker-compose файле, т.е. postgresqldb.
3. параметры конфигурации spring boot можно переопределять используя переменные окружения при запуске приложения. При этом точки обычно [нужно заменить](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) на подчеркивания. Т.е. параметр `spring.datasource.url` становится `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`.
4. При первом старте контейнера постгрес, создается база данных и по умолчанию ее имя будет такое же как указано в `POSTGRES_USER` (см. описание параметра `POSTGRES_DB` в [документации](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)), и именно ее я указал в `url` (это последняя часть после последнего слеша).

Comment: Я попробовал внести правки из  вашего совета, теперь ловлю другую ошибку: FATAL:  role "usrdb" does not exist

Внес изменения в файл application-por.properties в  hybridclient.jar на spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:5432//postgresqldb/db
spring.datasource.username=usrdb
spring.datasource.password=usrdb
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=9000
И в докер-композ на  
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=usrdb
      - POSTGRES_USER=usrdb

Comment: Сама конфигурация рабочая, специально только что проверил https://pastebin.com/sn1hvZhQ. Что-то делаете не так. В вашем комментарии пропало все форматирование и не видно всей картины, так что трудно что-то посоветовать.

Comment: Нашел свои ошибки, вы все правильно сказали. Спасибо!